# How to use an instance method in a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Category` model I have an instance method that adds up all the price averages for all products within a category:

```
def price_average(store_id)
  products.pluck(:price_average).map { |h| h[store_id] }.sum
end
```

In my `Category` controller I am trying to use a filter to only show categories where the `price_average` is above a specific amount. How can I do this?

My main challenge here is that `price_average` is not a column name so doing something like `@categories.where("price_average('1') > 1000")` just fails.

The structure of the models goes something like this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    # t.string "name"
    # t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    # t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false

    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    has_many :prices, through: :products

    def price_average(store_id)
      products.pluck(:price_average).map { |h| h[store_id] }.sum
    end
end


class Product < ApplicationRecord
    # t.string "name"
    # t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    # t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    # t.jsonb "price_average", default: {}

    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    has_many :prices

end
```

In the `price_average` column I'm storing json where store_id is the index used to retrieve the value.

Comment: Could you add the association details between category, products and store. Is price_average a hash? role of store_id? column type for price_average or is price_average again an instance method?

Comment: Just edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a column in your categories table called price_average and update it every time you add a product in a category or remove a product from a category then you can depend on this field after that.

note that this will save the processing time whenever you need to show an average more than you calculate it on runtime

Answer (score 0):

As understood from the question, proposing a solution using SQL queries, to optimise the solution, without changing the schema.

**Step 1:**

Get all the price_average of all the products where store_id is `STORE_ID`

```
# GET price_average of products, grouped on product and category. 
# This query would be a sub query to the next step.
# SQL code
SELECT 
    id, category_id, 
    (json_array_elements(products.price_average)->>'STORE_ID')::numeric as price_average 
    FROM products 
    GROUP BY id, category_id
```

**Step 2:**

Find sum of price_averages, and filter product and categories where sum is greater than `MIN_PRICE_AVERAGE_VARIABLE`

```
# SQL code
SELECT products.id, products.category_id, sum(products.price_average) as price_average 
        FROM (
            # Query from step 1
            SELECT id, category_id, (json_array_elements(products.price_average)->>'STORE_ID')::numeric as price_average 
            FROM products 
            GROUP BY id, category_id
            ) AS products 
        GROUP BY products.id, products.category_id
        HAVING sum(products.price_average) > MIN_PRICE_AVERAGE_VARIABLE
```

**Step 3:**

Get ids of the categories from Step 2, use the same to find all the categories. Using exec_query to execute the query, obtained in previous step.

```
# ruby code
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
result = @connection.exec_query("SELECT product_category.category_id FROM (
    SELECT products.id, products.category_id AS category_id, sum(products.price_average) as price_average  
    FROM (
    SELECT id, category_id, (json_array_elements(products.price_average)->>#{STORE_ID})::numeric as price_average 
            FROM products 
            GROUP BY id, category_id
    ) AS products 
    GROUP BY products.id, products.category_id
    HAVING sum(products.price_average)>#{MIN_PRICE_AVERAGE_VARIABLE} 
    ) AS product_category")
category_ids = result.rows.flatten.uniq
Category.where(id: category_ids)
```

Having said that, here is a schema change suggestion:

- it would be better to create a table with (product_id, category_id, store_id, average_price, other common columns).
- this would help finding a sum(average_price), filtered or grouped on any combination of the product_id, category_id, store_id.

Let me know if this helps. Thanks